# How to set ForeignKey and Index properties using IEntityTypeConfiguration in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am attempting to use the *EntityConfiguration* interface which is new in EF Core 2.0.

**Addendum** Probably helpful to see the Message class

```
public class Message 
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MessageForUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser MessageForUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MessageFromUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser MessageFromUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    public bool MessageRead { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime MessageCreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime? MessageReadOn { get; set; }
}
```

and the AppUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public SubscriptionLevel SubscriptionLevel { get; set; }
    public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> UserMessages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get;  set; }
}
```

Here is how the entity is defined in my `OnModelCreating` method.

```
builder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne(x => x.MessageForUser)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserMessages)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MessageForUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne(x => x.MessageFromUser)
            .WithMany(x => x.SentMessages)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MessageFromUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

My IEntityTypeConfiguration

```
public class AppUserConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {           
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(31);
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(55);
        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(u => u.DateOfBirth).HasColumnType("datetime");
        builder.Property(u => u.DateOfBirth).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(u => u.Gender).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

The EF 6 way had a `HasForeignKey` method off builder which is no longer available and I cant seem to find any way to add them.

Here is how the migration built the table from my `OnModelCreating` method. I'd like to put most of these items in my configuration class.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Messages_MessageForUserId",
            schema: "AppContext",
            table: "Messages",
            column: "MessageForUserId");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Messages_MessageFromUserId",
            schema: "AppContext",
            table: "Messages",
            column: "MessageFromUserId");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Messages_AspNetUsers_MessageForUserId",
            schema: "AppContext",
            table: "Messages",
            column: "MessageForUserId",
            principalSchema: "AppContext",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Messages_AspNetUsers_MessageFromUserId",
            schema: "AppContext",
            table: "Messages",
            column: "MessageFromUserId",
            principalSchema: "AppContext",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

There still is a `HasIndex` method, but I'm not sure how to duplicate what the migration is producing in the lambda expression for `HasIndex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HasForeignKey()` is still available in EF Core, just like you did in EF6. The misconception is, that it is not available on `EntityTypeBuilder<T>`, but on `ReferenceNavigationBuilder<T,K>`, which is the return type from `WithMany()`.

```
public class PostConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(y => y.Blog)
                .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogForeignKey);
    }
}


public class ApplicationContext :DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new PostConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Marco...There is no WithMany, there is HasMany, but my scenario is a bit different, at least how EF determined it, from the original migration. See the post update where I show the classes.

Comment: trying various approaches vis-a-vis your answer but not getting same migration code as original

Comment: Nowhere in your configuration class do you specifiy your relationship. If you do not specify your relationship in your `AppUserconfig`, you will not get `HasForeingKey()`, or do I misinterpret your problem? Just moving your OnModelCreating configuration in your config class would solve all your problems.

Comment: `HasForeignKey` API is available once you call `HasMany` or `HasOne` in any subsequent chain. There are multiple types which has the method since, different types are denoting different levels of configuration of relationship. Like `ReferenceNavigationBuilder` is relationship which has been configured with single reference navigation and inverse navigation is not specified/unknown.